# {noabort:1, E=noconntimeout:1} for Apache+nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This code apparently only works in Litespeed, I want the same code for Apache+nginx
And is it possible to put the code similar to this in the php file so that the script does not hang?

```
<IfModule Litespeed>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1, E=noconntimeout:1]
</IfModule>
```

I put this code at the beginning of my php script, but it hangs

`$execution_time_limit = 4500; set_time_limit($execution_time_limit);`